# Exercise after lesion

Tags: injury

I suffered a small lesion some weeks ago, and the spot is still a little bit sore, but no pain. Should I wait until I don't feel no soreness at all, or is it oK to restart exercising?

Answer (score 1):

Wait till you fully recover and 100% fit to carry on your workout. If the injury hasn't healed properly(soreness is an indication to that), then you may risk further damage. Also, consult with your doctor and take his advice on this.

Comment: Wouldn't you say exercising very light would actually help relieve him from the soreness?

Comment: @MJB: No, actually I wouldn't, Op said that there was a lesion, and we are not aware of the degree of soreness and what wasthe level of injury. I'd rather go for a safe bait.

Comment: Fair enough, you're right that we don't know the degree of soreness.